# I have a query in mongodb and the reference key's are in hashmap list , I need to process a simple query using java in mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb

mongodb  query is **db.test.find({"col1":{"$ne":""}}).count()**, I have tried many sources to find the solution, the "col1" must be populated from list array, please help me 
I have pasted a part of my code

`

```
List<String> likey = new ArrayList<String>();

for (DBObject o : out.results())
{
likey.add(o.get("_id").toString()); 
}

Iterator<String>itkey = likey.iterator();

DBCursor cursor ;

//cursor = table.find();

HashMap<String, String> hashmap = new HashMap<String, String>();

while (itkey.hasNext())
{
System.out.println((String)itkey.next());

String keys = itkey.next().toString();

//System.out.println("keys --> "+keys);

String nullvalue = "";

Boolean listone = table.distinct(keys).contains(nullvalue);


hashmap.put(keys, listone.toString());

//System.out.println("distinct --> "+keys+" "+listone);

//System.out.println("proper str --- >"+ '"'+keys+'"'); 
}

Iterator<String> keyIterator = hashmap.keySet().iterator();
Iterator<String> valueIterator = hashmap.values().iterator();

while (keyIterator.hasNext()) {
//System.out.println("key: " + keyIterator.next());


while (valueIterator.hasNext()) {
//System.out.println("value: " + valueIterator.next());

//System.out.println("Key: " + keyIterator.next() +""+"value: "+valueIterator.next());

String hashkey = valueIterator.next();

}

}
```

`

Comment: Don't dump in your whole code in here and say "help me". What exactly is your problem and what have you already tried?

Comment: The hashmap list consists of key names and I have to pass the key names to the mongodb collection to retrieve the blank record counts, the query I'm working for is db.test.find({"col1":{"$ne:""}}).count().col1 are the key names will be added from the list

Comment: Are you saying that what you're trying to do is retrieve the number of non-null entries in the database for each key?

Answer (score 0):

When you post code, it helps if you indent it, so it is more readable.  As I mentioned to you on another forum, you need to go back and review the Java collection classes, since you have multiple usage errors in the above code.

Here are a few things you need to do to clean up your code:

1) You don't need to use the itkey iterator.  Instead, use:

```
for (String key : likey)
```

and get rid of all the itkey.next calls.  Your current code only processes every second element of the List. The other ones are printed out.

2) Your HashMap will map a key to a Boolean.  Is that what you want? You said you want to count the number of non-zero values for the key.  So, the line:

```
Boolean listone = table.distinct(keys).contains(nullvalue);
```

is almost certainly in error.

3) When you iterate over the HashMap, you don't need the valueIterator.  Instead, get the key (either from the keyIterator, or a variable you define using the simpler iterator syntax above), then use the key to get the matching value using hashmap.get(key).

This will not make your code work, but it will clean it up somewhat - at the moment it is difficult to understand what you are intending it to do.